# Create multiple tasks from one single task

Tags: workflow, task-list

I am using SP2010.

In Tasks, I create a task and assigned it to a specific group which has 5 people. What I want is that the task has to be individually assigned to each person i.e. 5 new tasks of same Title etc must be created.

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workflow tasks are designed to be assigned to a single person or group only. If you are using the new Custom Task or Approval Process actions, they support expanding groups to assign a seperate task to each member of a group.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one technique from MSDN forums:

1. Create a new custom column of type User and Group. Check the "Allow multiple selections" option.
2. Add users and/or groups to the new column created in step 1.

Ref: [How to assign values to workflow task person or group custom field?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointworkflow/thread/ffca6f38-f7b4-4f23-b23d-65291f3f7997)

You can adjust the My Tasks view on the task list to show where new column is equal to [Me].

Comment: Excellent!! Will work on it!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a task, then initiate a workflow, assign the group in the workflow and then check the Expand Groups option to assign a task to each member of the group.

Answer (score 1):

you can use replicator activity to create a task for multiple peoples.